# Periodic "Batman" function?

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, quadratics, functional-equations, periodic-functions

I'm just wondering, is there a function that when graphed displays periodic "Batman" logos. This question is inspired by "Batman" equation.
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the function that takes a real $x=n\pi+t$, where $n$ is an integer and $\pi/2<t\leq \pi/2$ to $t$ as

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)).$$

So, if you scale the range of input of your "Batman" function that give a real output to the range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and it can be represented as the zero set of some function $f(x,y)$, you can represent a "periodic Batman function" as the zero set of

$$f\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\sin(x)\right),y\right).$$